# Magento: show new products in category

Tags: magento, categories, product

i can't find a solution for my problem:
i have a category with a layout.phtml created by me.
in this category i want to show only the new products (setted up by new from date and new to date fields) of this category.
i don't understand how to do this (xml or php no matter).
anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this to Get all new products filter by category Ids -

```
public function getProductCollection($catIds) {
$productIds = $this->getProductIdsByCategories($catIds);
$todayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
    $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
                        ->setStoreId($storeId)
                        ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
                        ->addMinimalPrice()
                        ->addTaxPercents()
                        ;
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);

    $collection
        ->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('news_to_date', array('or'=> array(
            0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),
            1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
        ), 'left')
        // ->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'desc')

        ;

    if(count($productIds)) {
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$productIds));
    }

    return $collection;
}
```

Hope it'll be Helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work, but i've resolved in this way (hope it helps someone):

- first, go to CMS -> WIDGETS, then create a widget of Catalog New Products List. inside, make a new layout update with: display on anchor categories,main content,products grid.
- second, go to template/catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml, and after  add this:

  ```
          $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
          $category_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
          $all_child_categories = $category_model->getResource()->getAllChildren($currentCategory);
  ```
- third, after foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product) add this:

  ```
      $visualizzo="";

          $diff = array_diff($all_child_categories, $_product->getCategoryIds());
          if(count($diff)==count($all_child_categories)){
              $visualizzo="display:none;";
          }
  ```
- last, in the li class="item" there's a style, put this in: